# Remove certain indexes in a list

Tags: python, loops, enumerate

Suppose I have a list filled with indexes to remove

```
remove = [0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 10, 11]
```

Then I have another list of lists, such as

```
l = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']]
```

I want to remove the values at the indexes in remove

Comment: As you delete elements, your indices change...

Comment: didnt even think about that

Comment: Do you get an error? Like an `IndexError`? My first guess is that since you remove the elements from the start, the right part of the list is shifted to the left each time you remove something, resulting in some of the indices you want to remove eventually are out of range.

Comment: The solution is to remove the elements starting with the greatest index, instead of the smallest.

Comment: Nope didn't get any error, just some elements dont get removed since after a few deletions it can no longer find some of the higher indexes like 9, 10, or 11

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to do this in place, you can construct new lists based on the index:

```
[[v for i, v in enumerate(s) if i not in to_remove] for s in l]
# [['b', 'd', 'g', 'i'], ['b', 'd', 'g', 'i']]
```

Comment: I am so confused as to what this means, i've never learned a syntax like this

Comment: This is `list comprehension`. It is a pretty common way to construct lists. You can google *list comprehension python* for more.

Comment: @JetAlex, you don't need to use a list comprehension. Psidom's idea is simple and nice if you can afford to copy the data.

Comment: It might be worth it to convert `to_remove` to a set beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

If you perform a step by step execution, the problem will become evident.

As you remove elements, the position of the following elements changes. For example, if you remove element 0 from a list, what was element 1 will become element 0.

If you want to stick with the current approach, just traverse the indices in reverse order (you don't need the values, just use a `range`).

Comment: i'm confused what this means "traverse the indices in reverse order"

Comment: @JetAlex Remove element at `11`, then at `10`, then at `9`, then at `7`...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want list comprehension, you can use a couple of loops like so:

```
for x in remove[::-1]:
    for list in l:
        del list[x]
```

> [['b', 'd', 'g', 'i'], ['b', 'd', 'g', 'i']]